# "json-server" command not found in Docker container even though it is installed

Tags: docker, json-server

I have a little application that I want to deploy in a docker container and in this container should also run a [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) on a different port to mock an API. During creation of the container the json-server is installed but when I try to run the server using `CMD` in the `Dockerfile` I only get the response that the command json-server is not found.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step    
RUN mkdir -p /app    
WORKDIR /app    
COPY package.json /app   
RUN npm install -g json-server 
RUN npm install    
COPY . /app    
RUN npm run build --prod 
 
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD json-server --watch services/mock-api/db.json --routes services/mock-api/routes.json --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

My .dockerignore file should not be relevant but here it is:

```
.git
.firebase
.editorconfig
/node_modules
/e2e
/docs
.gitignore
*.zip
*.md
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ale917k's answer did not work so I had to alter the Dockerfile a bit after more research:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2
FROM ubuntu:16.04
USER root
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY package.json /home/app/package.json
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install nginx
RUN npm i -g json-server

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/my-app/usr/share/nginx/html
CMD json-server --watch /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/mock-api/db.json --routes /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/mock-api/routes.json --no-cors --host 0.0.0.0
```

Very important to add: `-host 0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is you are trying to install the `json-server` dependency in a multi-stage container build, which means you can run related commands on that stage alone.

In order to get around this, you will need to move the package installation directly on your second stage so it can be accessed for running commands:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step    
RUN mkdir -p /app    
WORKDIR /app    
COPY package.json /app   
RUN npm install    
COPY . /app    
RUN npm run build --prod 
 
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN npm install json-server 

CMD json-server --watch services/mock-api/db.json --routes services/mock-api/routes.json --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Docker. So basically just moving my npm install commands to the second stage? Could you provide a fixed version?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, fixed it myself after some research. See below if you're interested.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? What was it throwing at that point? Glad you fixed anyway!

Comment: Did not find npm since I used nginx as base image. #16 0.402 /bin/sh: npm: not found

Comment: For that you could try `CMD ["npm", "install", "json-server;", "json-server", "--watch services/mock-api/db.json", "--routes services/mock-api/routes.json", "--port 3000", "--host 0.0.0.0"]` instead of the last two lines of your Dockerfile

Comment: Not sure if that works as I never tried running two commands in one on `CMD`, but I'd give it a shot as I feel like you are loosing performance basing your server on Ubuntu

Comment: I'll give it a shot on Monday, thank you.